# Cisco ASA IPsec tunnel disconnect sending RST to all hosts

Tags: vpn, cisco, tunnel, ipsec, asa

This is very strange behavior we are observing with our IPsec tunnel, we have two sites connected with cisco ASA using site-to-site VPN tunnel as per following:

`[LAN-1]---------[ASA-1]-------Internet-------[ASA-2]--------[LAN-2]`

We have Jenkin master on LAN-1 and some builds slave on LAN-2. In randomly by chance vpn tunnel blip out for few second, it causing jenkins disconnect to all slaves and distubes running job ( I felt like ASA sending `RST` packet when my tunnel blip out and that terminating all connection)

also if i have SSH connect established between LAN-1 and LAN-2 that SSH connection also got reset.

is it possible Cisco ASA send RST packet when tunnel go down for 10 second and re-initialize all `SA`?

Comment: I found this option `sysopt connection preserve-vpn-flows` and applied both side of ASA lets see if that fix my issue.

Comment: Damn still i am seeing all LAN connection getting dropped out

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw some ideas out there.

- Check the tunnel uptime. Relevant commands `show crypto isakmp sa` and
  `show crypto ipsec sa peer x.x.x.x`. Is it going down for sure?
- Can you replicate the issue by bouncing the tunnel? `clear crypto ipsec sa peer *x.x.x.x*`
- Definitely use `sysopt connection preserve-vpn-flows`. Did 
  you enable it on both sides or perhaps just one side?
- Can you run a packet capture to check for RST's being sent? This
  ideally is done on the host device but can also be done on the ASA
  with the `capture` command.